# How to get text among in blanket [] (Presto)

Tags: sql, regex, presto

How to get the result 'xxx' from blanket [ ] in presto.
I can't find the proper regexp to fix my problem

```
select aaa_[xxx]
```

Could you help me out?

Thank you

Comment: could you please provide input data example and desired output, it is not clear what are you asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have strings like this: and want to extract substring between square brackets, use this:

```
select regexp_extract('aaa_[xxx]','.*?\[(.*?)\]',1) --returns xxx
```